# ETL from RavenDB to SQL

Tags: sql, ravendb, etl

Are there any ETL tools available to export data from RavenDB?  Or will I be forced to write c# code to do the data migration?

The RavenDB is version 1 (build 888).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is builtin to the product. See: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/Csharp/server/bundles/sql-replication/basics

Comment: This is only available for RavenDB v3+ though right?  I would have to upgrade to v3 in order to use it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the creator of RavenDB also created [Rhino ETL](https://ayende.com/blog/3102/rhino-etl-2-0) to help with ETL. But it looks to be a .NET extension. Googling "RavenDB ETL" mostly came up with Rhino ETL.